# A neat and clean algorithm for the image resize 

Tags: python, algorithm, image

I need a better and clean algorithm for resizing and Image. My Images are mostly large and I want to resize it smaller size without much degradation of quality. I am using `python image library PIL`. Here I found  [An algorithm for resizing](http://united-coders.com/christian-harms/image-resizing-tips-general-and-for-python)  . when My Original image width is greater than the length then it seems to works fine but when length of original image is greater than the width of original image it (the algorithm) seems to be broken.

Please suggest me any better algo. Thanks

Comment: Show what you are currently doing to resize your image.

Comment: Also mention what you mean by broken. Is it giving wrong values ? Is it losing the aspect ratio ? Or does it error out somewhere during run time ?

Comment: @henry; I have given the link in my question. Same thing I have done ..

Comment: even copy and paste the code from the article that you are using right into this question, so we get the right context. It is unreasonable to expect people to read the article for you and then debug it. 1) show the code you are using, 2) tell us exactly what you expect, and how that's different from what you're getting

Comment: The link in your question discusses several techniques for resizing. Which one are you using (since you apparently won't post your code).

Answer (score 0):

I've used this before and it works for image with length > width and for any common image format.

```
img = Image.open(filename)
img.thumbnail((100,100))
```

Even in the case that the algo is broken for length > width but works when length < width. You can rotate the image by 90 degree first, resize it and rotate it back.

```
img=img.rotate(90)
```